# Remove special Character from complete table

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, procedure

I have 5 to 6 tables in which i am inserting data using Excel file but i don't know whats the issue but for some data special character are adding and that is giving me problem. So is their any way to update complete table by passing the only Table_name in some procedure.currently i am using one function to update the column but i want something more easy to use (for my other team member).
I am using below function .

```
create or replace FUNCTION pfm_on_varchar(
    p_str IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  o_str   VARCHAR2(4096) := '';
  asc_val NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1 .. LENGTH(p_str)
  LOOP
    asc_val := ascii(SUBSTR(p_str,i,1));
    IF ((asc_val BETWEEN 48 AND 57) OR (asc_val BETWEEN 65 AND 90) OR (asc_val BETWEEN 97 AND 122)) THEN
      o_str := o_str || chr(asc_val);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN o_str;
END pfm_on_varchar;
```

and how can I pass table name and column name in a procedure to update the table ?I am trying this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE removeSpecialChar(table_new IN varchar2, column_new IN varchar2)
AS
BEGIN 
  update table_new
  set column_new = PFM_ON_VARCHAR(column_new);
  end removeSpecialChar;
  /
```

Error I am getting

```
Error(4,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(4,10): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: Why PLSQL..You can do this in simple sql as well. Just make a case statement in select statement for the list of special characters you are getting and replace them with null.

Comment: This procedure will be very slow, you process each character one by one. Why not trying to solve the issue with character set?

Comment: The error suggests you have no table named `TABLE_NEW` in your schema. Dynamic SQL requires `execute immediate` and a quoted string.

Comment: thanks @WilliamRobertson 'execute immediate' is working perfectly.

Comment: if i am using single query like  `update table_name set c_name= PFM_ON_VARCHAR(c_name);`,it updating the complete column correctly,but what if i want to do this with above procedure ?cause its not working.how can i iterate column data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table
set columnName = regexp_replace('This is a test. $%&^*&* ', '[^A-Za-z .?!]', '')
```

Add all the characters which you don't want removed in the `[^A-Za-z .]`

For the procedure you could do a dynamic sql. Otherwise it will not pick the variable up. Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE removeSpecialChar(table_new IN varchar2, column_new IN varchar2)
AS
BEGIN 
  execute immediate 'update '||table_new||
  ' set '||column_new||' = PFM_ON_VARCHAR('||column_new||')';
  end removeSpecialChar;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments , you can try using `SQL` as below:

```
Update table1
set columnname =  case 
                    when ascii(columnname) between 48 and 54  
                    then replace (columnname,ascii(48),'')
                  end

where <condition> ;
```

Comment: [`ascii(str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions014.htm) only looks at the first character of `str`, so this might not work as hoped if the column has a longer value.

Comment: you are right its not working,because my column has longer values.